# How to draw a patatoid shape with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, irregular-shape

Is there a way to draw irregular, closed (2D) shapes, i.e. patatoids, using `tikz`? Something like these:
[image]

The ability to access the tangential and perpendicular directions to them at any given point, as well as to scale their sizes, would also be useful.

The shapes must not change as the document is compiled multiple times.

Thank you for your effort, it is very appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby, decorations.markings, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
\newcommand{\curve}{(-2,-1) .. (1,-2) .. (2,2) .. (0,1)}
\draw[
closed,
decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position 0.2 with {\draw[red, thick, -Stealth] (0,0) -- (0.6,0); \draw[thick, -Stealth] (0,0) -- (0,0.6);},
  mark=at position 0.3 with {\draw[red, thick, -Stealth] (0,0) -- (0.6,0); \draw[thick, -Stealth] (0,0) -- (0,0.6);},
  mark=at position 0.7 with {\draw[red, thick, -Stealth] (0,0) -- (0.6,0); \draw[thick, -Stealth] (0,0) -- (0,0.6);},
 },  
postaction={decorate},
] \curve;
\draw[closed, scale=0.8] \curve;
\draw[closed, scale=0.6] \curve;
\draw[closed, scale=0.4] \curve;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Concentric curves with tangent arrows]

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer!